# On Lemma 5.5.16 of Cisinski's "Higher Categories and Homotopical Algebra"

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

I have a question regarding Section 5 of Cisinski's
"Higher Categories and Homotopical Algebra".

Let us write $\mathbf{sSet}$ and $\mathbf{bisSet}$ for the categories of
simplicial sets and bisimplicial sets respectively.
There is a functor

$$
    -\boxtimes-
    \colon
    \mathbf{sSet}\times\mathbf{sSet}\to\mathbf{bisSet}
$$

that sends a pair of simplicial sets $A,B$ to the bisimplicial set
defined by $(A\boxtimes B)_{n,m}=A_n\times B_m$.
For each simplicial set $A$, the functors $A\boxtimes-$ and $-\boxtimes A$
have right adjoints, which we denote by ${}^A(-)$ and $(-)^A$ respectively.

In the proof of Lemma 5.5.16, it is claimed that there exists the following family of isomorphisms that are natural in simplicial sets $K, A, B$:

$$
    (A\boxtimes B)^K
    \cong
    A\times \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{sSet}}(K, B)
$$

where the right-hand side is the copower of the simplicial set $A$ by the set
$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{sSet}}(K,B)$.
In particular, the left-hand side admits a canonical map to $A$.

This claim is pivotal to the proof (and consequently to the proofs of 5.5.21 and 5.5.24), but I do not understand how this isomorphism is given.
For example, when $K=A=\emptyset$,
the left-hand side is the terminal object,
while the right-hand side is isomorphic to $A=\emptyset$
(and the terminal object $\Delta^0$ does not have any map to $\emptyset$).

Am I misunderstanding something?